# System of equations AX=B

Tags: matrices

Consider an arbitrary system of linear equations AX=B, where A and B are real matrices.

(a) Prove that if the system of equations AX=B has more that one solution then it has infinitely many.

(b) Prove that if there is a solution in the complex numbers then there is also a real solution

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

(a) Use two solutions to $AX=B$ to obtain a $Y$ such that $AY=0$. Then $Y$ can be rescaled at will and still remain in the kernel of $A$. Translating a solution $X$ by such $Y$s yields more solutions.

(b) Consider $\displaystyle{\rm Re}(X)=\frac{X+\bar{X}}{2}$ where $\bar{X}$ denotes conjugation (under which $A,B$ are invariant).

Comment: Could you please detail a little more part a) ?

Comment: @user43418 If $AX=B$ and $AY=0$ what can you say about $X+Y$?

Comment: Then $X+Y=A^{-1}B$

Comment: @user43418 No, you cannot assume $A$ is invertible. What happens when you apply $A$ to $X+Y$?

Comment: We then have A(X+Y)=B

Comment: Yes, so $X+Y$ is another solution. Now, if you can find infinitely many $Y$ such that $AY=0$ then you have infinitely many solutions to $AX=B$. And if you have one nonzero solution to $AY=0$, then you have infinitely many by rescaling. And you do have one nonzero solution to $AY=0$, namely $Y=X_1-X_2$ where $X_{1,2}$ are two different solutions to $AX=B$ by hypothesis.